# NSTimer thread issue

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have singleton that implements NSTimer object.

I run my timer using code below

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                                        target: self
                                                        selector: @selector(onTick:)
                                                        userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

I have `NSUInteger` instance variable that increase at each time when `- onTick:` method is called (so, once a second).

I have `UILabel` that represents date of my  `NSUInteger` instance variable and it works good. I have `UIScrollView` in my view as well. When I am scrolling it my `UILabel` does not update text. Even NSLog that shows info about timer tick in `- onTick:` method does not work. If I don't scroll timer begin works.

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5396764/249762