# UITableView scrolling causes a timer to stop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have just started taking an online course for ios app development and this is my first post on SO, so bear with me guys.

Taking further a stopwatch exercise, I managed to log laps into an array and the latter fills up a **UITableView** on the main storyboard.

Everything works fine except one thing, when I start scrolling the table, the stopwatch stops for some reason that I don't know and I hope that your answers will be understandable by a beginner.

I'm using **XCode 7**. Thanks.

As you might see, the code looks ugly and as I said these are my first lines in coding so I thought it would be better if I post it all.

To Summarise, the main story board contains two label for two counters, the main counter (timer) continue until reset button is pressed but the lapTimer is set to zero and its value is saved to the lapArr table, after which the counter starts again. here is all the code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

var timer = NSTimer()
var lapTimer = NSTimer()
var time = 0
var sec = 0
var min = 0
var lapTime = 0
var lapSec = 0
var lapMin = 0
var lap = ""
var lapArr = [""]


@IBOutlet var lapTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var lapCentiSecLab: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lapSecLab: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lapMinLab: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var mainCentiSecLab: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var mainSecLab: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var mainMinLab: UILabel!

func updateTime() {

    time++
    if time <= 9 {
        mainCentiSecLab.text = "0\(time)"
    } else {
        mainCentiSecLab.text = "\(time)"
    }
    if time == 99 {
        time = 0
        sec++
        if sec <= 9 {
            mainSecLab.text = "0\(sec)"
        } else {
            mainSecLab.text = "\(sec)"
        }
    }
    if sec == 59 {
        sec = 0
        min++
        if min <= 9 {
            mainMinLab.text = "0\(min)"
        } else {
            mainMinLab.text = "\(min)"
        }
    }
}

func updateTimeLap () {

    lapTime++
    if lapTime <= 9 {
        lapCentiSecLab.text = "0\(lapTime)"
    } else {
        lapCentiSecLab.text = "\(lapTime)"
    }

    if lapTime == 99 {
        lapTime = 0
        lapSec++
        if lapSec <= 9 {
            lapSecLab.text = "0\(lapSec)"
        } else {
            lapSecLab.text = "\(lapSec)"
        }
    }

    if lapSec == 60 {
        lapSec = 0
        lapMin++
        if lapMin <= 9 {
            lapMinLab.text = "0\(lapMin)"
        } else {
            lapMinLab.text = "\(lapMin)"
        }
    }
}

func lapTimeFormatter() {

    if lapTime <= 9 {
        lapCentiSecLab.text = "0\(lapTime)"
    } else {
        lapCentiSecLab.text = "\(lapTime)"
    }

    if lapSec <= 9 {
        lapSecLab.text = "0\(lapSec)"
    } else {
        lapSecLab.text = "\(lapSec)"
    }

    if lapMin <= 9 {
        lapMinLab.text = "0\(lapMin)"
    } else {
        lapMinLab.text = "\(lapMin)"
    }

}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1/100, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    lapTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1/100, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimeLap"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

@IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
    lapTimer.invalidate()

}



@IBAction func reset(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
    lapTimer.invalidate()

    time = 0
    sec = 0
    min = 0

    lapTime = 0
    lapSec = 0
    lapMin = 0

    lapTimeFormatter()

    mainCentiSecLab.text = "0\(time)"
    mainSecLab.text = "0\(sec)"
    mainMinLab.text = "0\(min)"

    lapArr.removeAll()
    lapTableView.reloadData()

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return (lapArr.count)

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = lapArr[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

@IBAction func lap(sender: AnyObject) {


    lapTimer.invalidate()

    lap = lapMinLab.text! + " : " + lapSecLab.text! + " . " + lapCentiSecLab.text!

    lapArr.append(lap)

    lapTime = 0
    lapSec = 0
    lapMin = 0

    lapTimeFormatter()

    lapTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1/100, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimeLap"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    lapTableView.reloadData()

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    lapTableView.allowsSelection = false
    lapTimeFormatter()

    mainCentiSecLab.text = "0\(time)"
    mainSecLab.text = "0\(sec)"
    mainMinLab.text = "0\(min)"

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: Please share the error logs and more information, this is too generic for anyone to help further.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help you though, we'll need to see some of your code

Comment: Thank you guys, which part of the code shall I post, or all of it ?

Comment: Show the code for how you start the timer, and how you load data into your table cells

Comment: Show the timer code and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code. Also, post any piece of code which calls `invalidate` method on timer from any where.

Comment: This question has been already asked many times already and have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5396764/229229

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz for redirecting me, I'm new here and as a beginner I found It hard to understand what does this NSRunLoop do exactly but It solved my problem anyways, thank you all.