# Scrolling locks updates to UIButton

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have some code in my UIView based on a timer like this:

```
//Start timer
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: {
            timer in

            if self.timerCount > 0 {

                let minutes = Int(self.timerCount/60)
                let seconds = Int(self.timerCount%60)

                UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                    self.proxyView!.confirmButton.setTitle(CHRText.apptConfirmButton + " (" + String(describing:minutes) + ":" + String(describing: seconds) + ")", for: UIControlState.normal)
                }
                self.timerCount -= 1
            }
            else{
                self.timer!.invalidate()
            }

        })
```

The code works fine, except for one issue. When I am scrolling a UIScrollView also in the view, the button title will not update. After I complete my scrolling, all updates to the title occur in rapid succession as if queued. How can I have this text continually update without freezing while scrolling?

Comment: Did you try wrapping the UI updates inside of the main queue?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377914/uilabel-updating-stops-during-scrolling-uiscrollview ?

Comment: @Sulthan I have not, but that's exactly what I need. I've voted to close with duplicate.