# How to update label text in scroll view ios

Tags: ios, timer, label, scrollview

I have a label inside a scroll view iOS.
And a timer to update the label text. 
It work OK but if I'm scrolling the scroll view, the label does not update

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) countDown {
      label.text = [[NSDate date] description];
}
```

Answer here: [My custom UI elements are not being updated while UIScrollView is scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109898/my-custom-ui-elements-are-not-being-updated-while-uiscrollview-is-scrolled)

Comment: Show us the code. Also describe exactly what you expect and are seeing/not seeing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109898/my-custom-ui-elements-are-not-being-updated-while-uiscrollview-is-scrolled

Here is the answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onTick:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
   label.text = //what you want.
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: It can not update label text when I'm scrolling the scroll view

Answer (score 0):

Use this UIScrollViewDelegate method to update the label

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
   // here update your label
}
```