# Scrolling stops animations iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation, caanimation

My problem is quite simple, on my UIVIewController i have a custom UIView which is animated using CAAnimation and UIViewAnimation, i also have a UIScrollView, when the scrollView is scrolling the animated UIView stop all its animations !

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self 

selector:@selector(updateClock:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
hourHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (hourAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
...
```

In the Animated View i use : NSTimer, QuartzCore, and UIViewAnimation.

How can avoid this ? It is because i use a custom UIView ? (I'm still a beginner)

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be interested in this SO question. [UIScrollView scroll event blocks UIView animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557846/uiscrollview-scroll-event-blocks-uiview-animation)

The proposed solution is to add the `timer` to the current loop.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: it's ok just change NSDefaultRunLoopMode to NSRunLoopCommonModes

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference please ?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222449/nsdefaultrunloopmode-vs-nsrunloopcommonmodes