# UIView with UITableView Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to fade `UIView` that contain `UITableView` with :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 animations:^{
    [self.relatedTableView setAlpha:0.9];
}];
```

The problem is that in this 10 seconds i can't scroll the `UITableView`, Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389454/uitableviewcell-animations-stop-when-uitableview-is-scrolling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

    [self.relatedTableView setAlpha:0.9];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"Done");

}];
```