# Is there a way to specify the run loop & mode to to receive elements from a publisher

Tags: swift, uikit, combine, runloop

I can specify the scheduler as `RunLoop.main`, but I could not find a native way to provide the associated `RunLoop.Mode` mode to receive elements from a publisher.

**Why do I need this:** I'm updating a tableView cell from my publisher but the UI does not update if the user is scrolling, it then updates as soon as the user interaction or scroll stops. [This is a known behaviour for scrollViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109898/my-custom-ui-elements-are-not-being-updated-while-uiscrollview-is-scrolled/4136988) but I want my content to be displayed as soon as possible, and being able to specify the run loop tracking mode would fix this.

**Combine API:** I do not think the `receive(on:options:)` method [have any matching options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204743-receive) to provide this. I think internally, if I call `receive(on:RunLoop.main)` then `RunLoop.main.perform { }` is called. This perform method can take [the mode as parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/2091880-perform) but this is not exposed to the Combine API.

---

**Current Idea:** To go around this I could do the perform action myself and not use the Combine API, so instead of doing this:

```
cancellable = stringFuture.receive(on: RunLoop.main) // I cannot specify the mode here
                          .sink { string in
    cell.textLabel.text = string
}
```

I could do this:

```
cancellable = stringFuture.sink { string in
    RunLoop.main.perform(inModes: [RunLoop.Mode.common]) { // I can specify it here
        cell.textLabel.text = string
    }
}
```

But this is not ideal.

**Ideal Solution:** I was wondering how could I wrap this into my own implementation of a publisher function to have something like this:

```
cancellable = stringFuture.receive(on: RunLoop.main, inMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
                          .sink { string in
    cell.textLabel.text = string
}
```

Were the API of this function could be something like this:

```
extension Publisher {
    public func receive(on runLoop: RunLoop, inMode: RunLoop.Mode) -> AnyPublisher<Future.Output, Future.Failure> {

        // How to implement this?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what you've requested is custom `Scheduler`, because RunLoop is a `Scheduler` and running it in specific mode, instead of `.default`, is just additional configuration of that scheduler.

I think that Apple will add such possibility in their `RunLoop` scheduler in some of next updates, but for now the following simple custom scheduler that wraps `RunLoop` works for me. Hope it would be helpful for you.

Usage:

```
.receive(on: MyScheduler(runLoop: RunLoop.main, modes: [RunLoop.Mode(rawValue: "myMode")]))
```

or

```
.delay(for: 10.0, scheduler: MyScheduler(runLoop: RunLoop.main, modes: [.common]))
```

Scheduler code:

```
struct MyScheduler: Scheduler {
    var runLoop: RunLoop
    var modes: [RunLoop.Mode] = [.default]

    func schedule(after date: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType, interval: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
                    tolerance: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride, options: Never?,
                    _ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Cancellable {
        let timer = Timer(fire: date.date, interval: interval.magnitude, repeats: true) { timer in
            action()
        }
        for mode in modes {
            runLoop.add(timer, forMode: mode)
        }
        return AnyCancellable {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func schedule(after date: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType, tolerance: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
                    options: Never?, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let timer = Timer(fire: date.date, interval: 0, repeats: false) { timer in
            timer.invalidate()
            action()
        }
        for mode in modes {
            runLoop.add(timer, forMode: mode)
        }
    }

    func schedule(options: Never?, _ action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        runLoop.perform(inModes: modes, block: action)
    }

    var now: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType { RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType(Date()) }
    var minimumTolerance: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride { RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride(0.1) }

    typealias SchedulerTimeType = RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType
    typealias SchedulerOptions = Never
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `DispatchQueue.main` to the `receive(on:options:)` because `DispatchQueue` also comforms to `Scheduler` protocol.

Somehow it makes deliver events while scrolling.

Like the following:

```
cancellable = stringFuture.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                          .sink { string in
    cell.textLabel.text = string
}
```

Comment: that doesn't allow specifying the run mode though. Default mode is not processed during a gesture tracking event (such as when scrolling, while your finger is down)